# ORA-01722 invalid number on using the expression in select and while joining

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CASE WHEN (r.code_value4 = 0 AND LENGTH(ltrim(rtrim(xx.AFFILIATE_CODE))) > 0) AND 
          r_intercompany.code_value1 is not null AND 
          ltrim(rtrim(xx.AFFILIATE_CODE)) <> (CASE WHEN xx.COMPANY_CODE_JE_EXCEPTION_FLAG = 1 
                                                   THEN r.code_value3 ELSE r.code_value1 END)
     THEN r_intercompany.code_value1
     ELSE NVL(r_mga_acct.code_value2, xx.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) END
```

I have view in which the above part of the sql is being used in select statement and as well as to compare with a field while joining. When I run the view after making this change, it is throwing the error ORA-01722 invalid number.

Please let me know on how to correct this.

Thanks

Comment: What change did you do? how it was before change? my first suspicion is `NVL(r_mga_acct.code_value2, xx.ACCOUNT_NUMBER)` what are types of both fields there - `r_mga_acct.code_value2` and  `xx.ACCOUNT_NUMBER`? UPD and yes how about `r.code_value4 = 0`?

Comment: This is not a very good question. Please provide more details. What are the types of these columns? Where's the rest of the query? Can you give us a working example?

Comment: @Vadim I didn't had this join and this condition in the view at all. This is a new join. r_mga_acct.code_value2 , xx.ACCOUNT_NUMBER both are of varchar type.r.code_value4 is also varchar. rewrote code as TO_NUMBER(r.code_value4) but same error.

Answer (score 2):

> " it is throwing the error ORA-01722 invalid number."

It is likely somewhere you are comparing a numeric column with a string column . Oracle is implicitly casting the string to a number but the column contains values which cannot be converted, so it hurls.

> "Please let me know on how to correct this."

Don't rely on implicit data conversion. Go through your code, check the data types of all the columns. Where you find a varchar2 column being compared to a number you need to cast the number to a string. For literals that means quoting them - `'1'` instead of `1` - and for columns that means wrapping them in `to_char()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

My Suspicion is either r.code_value4 field  or xx.COMPANY_CODE_JE_EXCEPTION_FLAG field is String type hence try the below

```
CASE WHEN (r.code_value4 = '0' AND LENGTH(ltrim(rtrim(xx.AFFILIATE_CODE))) > 0) AND 
      r_intercompany.code_value1 is not null AND 
      ltrim(rtrim(xx.AFFILIATE_CODE)) <> (CASE WHEN xx.COMPANY_CODE_JE_EXCEPTION_FLAG = '1' 
                                               THEN r.code_value3 ELSE r.code_value1 END)
 THEN r_intercompany.code_value1
 ELSE NVL(r_mga_acct.code_value2, xx.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) END
```

Comment: Tried it. Getting the same error ORA-01722 Invalid Number

Comment: Provide sample data for checking